# CSV as Associative Array

Tags: php

I have a CSV file I would like to use as an array in a script.

The CSV is simple:

```
key1,val1
key2,val2
...
```

I want to be able to reference the array created like this:

```
$value = my_csv['key'];
```

I currently cannot do that because my script shows the index as undefined.

```
$myArray = array();
$file = fopen('myCSV.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  array_push($myArray, array($line[0] => $line[1]));
}
fclose($file);
var_dump($myArray['key']);
exit;
```

I believe this is because I would need to use the numerical index first but I would ideally be able to reference the array in the way I am above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array needs to be created with the key set then, like this

```
$myArray = array();
$file = fopen('myCSV.csv', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  $myArray[$line[0]] = $line[1];
}
fclose($file);
var_dump($myArray['key']);
```

This does assume that there are no duplicates in the `key`